# NEXT JS environment variables not working in my local system

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

I am relatively new to the Next.js, and for some reason, in my local system I can not access environment variables. I am giving all the related files here.

`pages/index.js`

```
import type {NextPage} from 'next'
import {useEffect} from "react";

const Home: NextPage = (props) => {

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("From Client API_URL:", process.env.API_URL)
        console.log("From Client NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL:", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            Hello World!
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    console.log("From Client API_URL:", process.env.API_URL)
    console.log("From Client NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL:", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)
    return {
        props: {
            hello: "World!"
        }
    }
}

export default Home
```

`.env.local` file

```
API_URL:https://fakestoreapi.com/
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL:https://fakestoreapi.com/
```

In the browser, I am getting this in the console.

[image: browser error]

In the server, I am getting this

```
> npm run dev

> dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\...\next-app\.env.local
warn  - SWC minify beta enabled. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-minify-enabled
event - compiled client and server successfully in 361 ms (217 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 92 ms (220 modules)
From server API_URL: undefined
From server NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: undefined
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 78 ms (221 modules)
```

next js version: 12.0.7

node js version: 14.17.1

npm version: 8.1.4

Comment: You have a typo, you need to use a `=` to assign a value to an environment variable in your `.env` file, i.e. `API_URL=https://fakestoreapi.com/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems your `.env.local` not properly config ,
you should when assigning value to a key using = not :

**.env.local**

```
API_URL=https://fakestoreapi.com/
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://fakestoreapi.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access your environment variables in the browser you need to prefix your environment variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`

Without this prefix you will find that your environment variable is not available.

See this [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) to learn more about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, my issue is solved after the .env.local file is put inside the src/app folder.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` initial works when you want to make use of the variable on the client side.

instead of:

```
API_URL=https://fakestoreapi.com/
```

Use this:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://fakestoreapi.com/
```

Answer (score -4):

You cannot access keys in .env files on client side in Next.js which doesnot start with NEXT_PUBLIC_ .

Also, your file should be .env .

**.env**

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL:https://fakestoreapi.com/
```

**pages/index.js**

```
import type {NextPage} from 'next'
import {useEffect} from "react";

const Home: NextPage = (props) => {

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("From Client API_URL:", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)
        console.log("From Client NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL:", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            Hello World!
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    console.log("From Client API_URL:", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)
    console.log("From Client NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL:", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)
    return {
        props: {
            hello: "World!"
        }
    }
}
```

export default Home

Comment: I am following both the rules you've mentioned in my question above. still, I could not access NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL which is in file .env.local as per the documentation [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

Comment: @RushiRami I think this is correct : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70492256/5599770